# Python Object error/Index error when attempting to override

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, overriding, hierarchy

I am working on a college assignment, this week I am attempting to override a previous function to show heritage/how to override. I encountered a slight issue however. The prior function: getDescriptiveInfo, doesn't work when I attempt to override it. I am passing the same data through and it simply doesn't work. While experimenting/trouble shooting I found that if I remove the object and call the class/function directly, it gives me an array error (which doesn't appear if I call the function through an object)

```
Original/Parent getDescriptiveInfo:


def getDescriptiveInfo(self, list1 = [], list2 = [], list3 = []):
        #   This function creates a dictonary, runs through the required processes before adding them to the dictionary.
        #   It does this for each list provided. I believe there is some way to reduce the redundant code yet I have been unable to figure it out.

        Results = {}

        array1 = np.array(list1)

        dimension_1 = np.ndim(array1)
        Results.update({"List_1_Demensions": dimension_1})
        
        shape_1 = np.shape(array1)
        Results.update({"List_1_Shape": shape_1})

        last_item1 = array1[-1, -1]
        Results.update({"List_1_Last_Item": last_item1})

        column_zero1 = array1[:, 0]
        Results.update({"List_1_Column_Zero": column_zero1})

        second_row1 = array1[0:2, :]
        Results.update({"List_1_Second_Row": second_row1})

        array2 = np.array(list2)

        dimension_2 = np.ndim(array2)
        Results.update({"List_2_Demensions": dimension_2})
        
        shape_2 = np.shape(array2)
        Results.update({"List_2_Shape": shape_2})

        last_item2 = array2[-1, -1]
        Results.update({"List_2_Last_Item": last_item2})

        column_zero2 = array2[:, 0]
        Results.update({"List_2_Column_Zero": column_zero2})

        second_row2 = array2[0:2, :]
        Results.update({"List_2_Second_Row": second_row2})

        array3 = np.array(list3)

        dimension_3 = np.ndim(array3)
        Results.update({"List_3_Demensions": dimension_3})
        
        shape_3 = np.shape(array3)
        Results.update({"List_3_Shape": shape_3})

        last_item3 = array3[-1, -1]
        Results.update({"List_3_Last_Item": last_item3})

        column_zero3 = array3[:, 0]
        Results.update({"List_3_Column_Zero": column_zero3})

        second_row3 = array3[0:2, :]
        Results.update({"List_3_Second_Row": second_row3})

        print(Results)
        print(len(Results))
```

The Child class/call:

```
class NewNetworkCheck(NetworkCheck):
    
    def __init__(self):
        NetworkCheck.__init__(self)
    
    def getDescriptiveInfo(self, list1 = [], list2 = [], list3 = []):
        NetworkCheck.getDescriptiveInfo(self, list1 = [], list2 = [], list3 = [])
```

The Array/Index error I get is this:
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

Any suggestions or hints on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated! I just need a hint or something to point me in the right direction. Thank you for your time!

I tried to override the parent function and receievd an index error. I attempted to fix this by changing variables arround to no avail.

EDIT: Full error below.

````
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Network\MyTest.py", line 134, in <module>
    New.getDescriptiveInfo(list1=cm.SubList1, list2=cm.SubList2, list3=cm.SubList3)
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Network\Package\NewNetworkCheck.py", line 10, in getDescriptiveInfo
    NetworkCheck.getDescriptiveInfo(self, list1 = [], list2 = [], list3 = [])
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Network\Package\NetworkCheck.py", line 71, in getDescriptiveInfo
    last_item1 = array1[-1, -1]
                 ~~~~~~^^^^^^^^
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed```
````

Comment: Show the full error message

Comment: @hpaulj Posted the full error code. Hope it helps!

Comment: tell us about `cm.SubList1`.  `nparray(cm.SubList1)` should produce a 2d array for this code to work.